# Get an SVG from a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a react app that creates an SVG from text input.

It provides a few text inputs and has a context provider and a component SVGOutput. The JSX is constructed like this:

```
return(
    <>
    <SomeInputFields/>
    <ContextProvider value{{
        someVariables,
        forTheContext
    }}>
        <TextOptions/>
        <SVGOutput/>
    </ContextProvider>
    </>
);
```

The SVGOutput component has a JSX like this

```
return (
  <svg
    version="1.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  >
    {
      svgData.map((svgPath, i) =>
        <path
          key={i}
          fill={svgPath.fill}
          d={svgPath.d}
          transform={svgPath.transform}
        />
      )
    }
  </svg>
);
```

I tried using `renderToString` from `react-dom/server` to get the SVG but it does not quite work, the SVG is empty, the paths that are into the DOM while using the apps don't get rendered into the String.

```
renderToString(
    <ContextProvider value{{
        someVariables,
        forTheContext
    }}>
        <SVGOutput/>
    </ContextProvider>
    </>
);
```

With some text on the SVG calling this function gives me a string without the path elements.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="height:[object Object];width:800px" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" width="20" height="20"></svg>
```

I am assuming this is because renderToString does not get the updated component but the component as it looks on first render?

Is there a possibility to get the current state of `<SVGOutput>` as a string?

The only other option I can imagine is tying an external function to the window object and in that function have "vanilla javascript" select the svg element and get it as a string...? But is there an option using that within react?

Comment: What if you add a ref to the svg and then use ref.current.innerHTML?

Comment: I didn't think of ref, but yes might be possible

Comment: I have now tried to ref the <SVGOutput ref={SVGRef}> component but i always get the error "Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()" I tried it with forwardRef but that causes the same error again.

Comment: ref should be in the <svg> tag

Comment: yeah thanks if figured it out, either that or a div around the <SVGOutput> component

Comment: cool, will add it as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this, is to use a `ref` in the `<svg>` tag, and then get the string from `ref.current.innerHTML`.